# Transform.Parent not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with objects. I have several objects that they interchange with each other.

```
    private void BottleClicked(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
        int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(BottleObj, target);
        BottlesInterchange(targetIndex);
        hasOne = true;
    }
}

private void BottlesInterchange(int targetIndex)
{
    BottleObj[targetIndex].transform.DOScale(1.1f, 0.5f).SetEase(Ease.OutBack);
    if (hasOne)
    {
        canClick = false;
        if (targetIndex != lastTargetIndex)
        {
            /*
            myBottleSequence.Bottles[targetIndex].transform.parent = myBottleSequence.ParentPositions[lastTargetIndex].transform;
            myBottleSequence.Bottles[lastTargetIndex].transform.parent = myBottleSequence.ParentPositions[targetIndex].transform;      
            */

            BottleObj[lastTargetIndex].transform.DOScale(1f, 0.5f).SetEase(Ease.OutBack);
            BottleObj[targetIndex].transform.DOScale(1f, 0.5f).SetEase(Ease.OutBack);
            BottleObj[lastTargetIndex].transform.DOMove(BottleObj[targetIndex].transform.position, 1f);
            BottleObj[targetIndex].transform.DOMove(BottleObj[lastTargetIndex].transform.position, 1f).OnComplete(() =>
            {
                hasOne = false;
                canClick = true;                    
            });
        }
    }
    lastTargetIndex = targetIndex;
}
```

So, the commented code is what I'm trying to do. It works only once, so the first time I select an object and interchange it, they change their parents, but the second time no longer works, that is, when they interchange the same objects. if I select another object and then interchange it, they  change their parents, then they do not change anymore. If anyone has any idea what's going on, thank you !!!

Comment: why, what have I wrong?

Comment: I think you should argue why my code is not working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        /*
        myBottleSequence.Bottles[targetIndex].transform.parent = myBottleSequence.ParentPositions[lastTargetIndex].transform;
        myBottleSequence.Bottles[lastTargetIndex].transform.parent = myBottleSequence.ParentPositions[targetIndex].transform;      
        */
```

Abstract:

```
Parent of A is now B; (so A becomes child of B)
Parent of B is now A; (so B becomes child of A)
```

Do you see your problem? This is (like) a simple swapping problem:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;

// wrong "swap"
a = b;
b = a;
// result: a = 5, b = 5

// correct swap:
int c = a; // buffer
a = b;
b = c;
// result: a = 5, b = 2;
```

So all you need to do is use a buffer variable:

```
Transform buffer_parent = myBottleSequence.Bottles[targetIndex].transform.parent;

 myBottleSequence.Bottles[targetIndex].transform.parent = myBottleSequence.ParentPositions[lastTargetIndex].transform;
 myBottleSequence.Bottles[lastTargetIndex].transform.parent = buffer_parent;
```

Comment: you are right, but it is a problem, however, when I select the same combination of objects for the second time, both become children for one parent

Comment: very correctly the code written by you, but you also forgot the second one:

Comment: I've corrected your code, thanks a lot, now it works perfectly. :)